# httpd not loading httpd.conf file when loading through rc script

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, fedora, httpd

Binary is located in `/usr/sbin/`

When I ran `strace -o httpdstart.txt /usr/bin/httpd -k start`

It has the following lines to open the `httpd.conf`

```
stat("/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=35894, ...}) = 0
open("/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
```

So when loading manually via:

```
httpd -k start
```

or

```
/usr/bin/httpd -k start
```

`httpd` loads as expected with the `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` for configuration.

I also ran `strace -o httpdstart.txt /etc/init.d/httpd -k start`

i get:

```
Usage: httpd {start|stop|restart|condrestart|try-restart|force-reload|reload|status|fullstatus|graceful|help|configtest}
```

So the usage says that I cannot use any option with httpd rc script.

So I ran `strace -o httpdstart1.txt /etc/init.d/httpd start`. It does not have trace of opening any `httpd.conf` file.

---

the httpd rc script in init.d has:

```
apachectl=/usr/sbin/apachectl
httpd=${HTTPD-/usr/sbin/httpd}
```

i.e. its pointing to the proper binary file.

---

`httpd -V` has the following output:

> Server version: Apache/2.2.21 (Unix)
>   Server built:   Sep 13 2011 13:46:54
>   Server's Module Magic Number: 20051115:30
>   Server loaded:  APR 1.4.5, APR-Util 1.3.10
>   Compiled using: APR 1.4.5, APR-Util 1.3.12
>   Architecture:   64-bit
>   Server MPM:     Prefork
>     threaded:     no
>       forked:     yes (variable process count)
>   Server compiled with....
>    -D APACHE_MPM_DIR="server/mpm/prefork"
>    -D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
>    -D APR_HAS_MMAP
>    -D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)
>    -D APR_USE_SYSVSEM_SERIALIZE
>    -D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
>    -D SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT
>    -D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
>    -D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
>    -D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=128
>   **-D HTTPD_ROOT="/etc/httpd"**
>    -D SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/sbin/suexec"
>    -D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="logs/httpd.pid"
>    -D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
>    -D DEFAULT_LOCKFILE="logs/accept.lock"
>    -D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"
>    -D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="conf/mime.types"
>    **-D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="conf/httpd.conf"**

---

When loaded through rcscript, DocumentRoot doesn't get set and

```
ErrorDocument 403 /error/noindex.html
```

happens(present in welcome.conf), and loads the `Fedora Test Page`. If I remove the welcome.conf. I will get a `Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server`.
What is it that is going wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like it's two different apaches. One was at /usr/**bin**/httpd and the other at /usr/**sbin**/httpd. Try manually starting the "sbin" one and see if the output of httpd -V is the same as when it starts up through the rc script.

Comment: There is no `httpd` present in `/usr/bin`

Comment: and yes that output is the same as `/usr/sbin/httpd -V`

Comment: Hmm.. as a work around, could you use the '-f' argument to specify a config file in the /etc/init.d/httpd script? That script also makes mention of an alternate conf file located in /etc/sysconfig/httpd.. does it have anything to do with it?

Comment: One more thing, I am trying to start httpd during the startup.

Comment: My guess would be under that Start() function, like "LANG=$HTTPD_LANG daemon --pidfile=${pidfile} $httpd -f "/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf" $OPTIONS". I don't have an idle web server to test it on though, so I have no idea if it will work like I'm thinking it will.

Comment: actually I am already doing it ... :)

Comment: sadly its not working now I get this `[Fri Jan 13 19:46:22 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.21 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.3.8 mod_python/3.3.1 Python/2.7.1 mod_ssl/2.2.21 OpenSSL/1.0.0e-fips mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.12.4 configured -- resuming normal operations`
and `[Fri Jan 13 20:46:16 2012] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down`
May be I am doing some mistake.. Still looking into it.

Comment: Try /usr/sbin/httpd -f "/path/to/httpd.conf" -t to do a syntax check and see if the syntax is ok

Comment: already did that still a `SIGTERM` is still getting caught